# How to export mestimate filter motion vectors into a separate file with ffmpeg binary?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, encoding, codec

So [mestimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mestimate) filter can be used to compute the motion vectors in a video. They can also be [displayed](https://gist.github.com/fritschy/be8ed6240fbc33b78243fe52f5442a5e#file-ffmpeg-one-liners-sh-L18). Is there a way to export them into a separate file using the ffmpeg binary? I would love to have them for example in an image like 2-component color values representing the 2D vectors for each block (so the resolution would be the original one divided by the block size) or something.
Given a sequence of png frames, I can do:

```
ffmpeg -i %04d.png -vf "mestimate" test.mkv
```

And as I understand it, the vectors are then stored in the [frames' side data](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/structAVFrameSideData.html) which can be extracted using libav. Is there a simple way with the ffmpeg tool alone? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible using FFmpeg. Take a look at [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24814/extracting-motion-vectors-from-h-264-bitstream). I think a text file is more appropriate format than a color coded image.

Comment: Thanks @Rotem. Yea, I know it's possible using the C library. Was wondering if ffmpeg binary offers some options to achieve this.

Comment: I thought there is also a tool named `MV-Tractus`, but the project looks like a Linux Python student project. The best solution I could find is building [extract_mvs.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/extract__mvs_8c_source.html). We have to link it with FFmpeg `.lib` files in Windows or `.so` files in Linux (in Windows the LIB files are downloaded with the FFmpeg "shared" version). I had a project ready in Visual Studio, so it took me few minutes to build... it's working as command line tool `extract_mvs.exe test.mkv` (printing a long list).

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much @Rotem